# Could someone distinguish the noun phrase and the verb phrase parts of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to parse a sentence with a bottom-up parser for a Natural Language Processing assignment but I'm stuck as to which part of the sentence is the noun phrase and verb phrase. Any help about this would be appreciated!

Sentence - **The corpse rose from the dead**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In traditional grammar the **noun phrase** (NP), is the thing before the predicate, i.e. "The corpse", its function is also subject:

[ [**The corpse**] [*rose from the dead*] ]

*...rose from the dead*, is the predicate (it contains the verb and gives information about the subject)

*...rose from the dead* is also ***the verb phrase*** (VP).

The verb phrase tells us what kind of thing the 'predicate' is.

- In English, the Predicate in a sentence is always a verb phrase. (Not all verb phrases are Predicates, though!)

Comment: That helps a ton. Thank you so much for providing the reasons for how the sentence is structured as you stated.